# zf2 URI rewrites like magento

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

i'm new to zend and i want to create a small application with zf2.

my problem is about seo-friendly-urls.

for my project i want urls like 'domain.tld/my-product-xyz' (requestPath)

actually i only have urls like 'domain.tld/module/action/id' (targetPath)

i know from magento that it is possible to store the requestPath and targetPath in a database, in order to fetch the right targetPath by searching for the requestPath.

i have read the following article about custom routing in zf2 and made everything like he wrote:
http://www.zendexperts.com/2012/12/09/custom-routing-in-zend-framework-2/

i think i just have to edit this function, but i dont know how.

```
public function match(Request $request, $pathOffset = null)
{
    // get the service locator
    $serviceLocator = $this->routePluginManager->getServiceLocator();

    //@todo do something with the request and return an RouteMatch instance

    return false;
}
```

i figured out how to create a working RouteMatch-Object, but in my opinion it is a way to complicated and i think there is an easier way to do it, because for each url i have so store the right module, action and id in the database:

```
    $routematchvar->setParam('controller','Module/Controller/Module');
    $routematchvar->setParam('action','action');
    $routematchvar->setParam('id', 'id');

    return $routematchvar;
```

is it possible to change the URI of the request-object? i tried it with following command: $request->setUri( targetPath ). but zend just stops working and writes out the targetPath.

sorry for my bad english :(
thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easiest way to achieve this is by using [RegEx Route's](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-regex). The documentation is pretty ok and should make a few things clear. Keep in mind it is pretty important to use the "format" in your RegEx otherwise your routes will fail.

You could indeed also extend the matching but using build in functionality is usually the better aproach.